# Regex do not allow only numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex to validate some data,  I need it to match the following rules...

- Only allow alphanumeric characters
- Have at least 2 characters
- Does not consist of only numbers

I have this regex so far http://regex101.com/r/nC4hZ8...

```
(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*
```

This is working apart from it allows it to consist of all numbers.  So for example the following test data should all fail....

```
47
4
83874
```

But the following should pass

```
47 apple
apple
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You're saying that the space between '47' and 'apple' should be a valid character as well?

Comment: http://rubular.com/ is a useful testing tool, although anubhava's link also looks fantastic.

Comment: Take care to correctly specify the problem.  "47" should fail but should " 47" and "47 " also fail?

Comment: I would also suggest using http://www.regexr.com/ as a way of batch-testing data. It also has a lot of tips and a few examples at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?![0-9]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{2,}$
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lL3uT4)

Comment: Thanks, nice compact version

Answer (score 1):

`([a-z][a-z0-9]+|[a-z0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z0-9]+[a-z][a-z0-9]+)`

EDIT: matching space too

`([a-z][a-z0-9 ]+|[a-z0-9 ]+[a-z]|[a-z0-9 ][a-z]+[a-z0-9 ])`

Comment: the test data item '47 apple' does not validate using that

Comment: @fightstarr20 a space is not an alphanum